# How can I access excel properties like creation date with C# and Excel interop

Tags: c#, office-interop, com-interop, excel-interop

I have to extract the creation date of an excel file using C# and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet`. 
I will get the properties with

```
object props = myworkbook.CustomDocumentProperties;
```

Now I am not sure how to get the creation date from this object.

Comment: I am somewhat confused about your question. Of course there is a property `WorkBookClass.BuiltinDocumentProperties` through which you should be able to access the creation date...

Comment: Sorry my question is very bad. I cannot understand how to use the `CustomDocumentProperties` to get the creation date. I have to edit my question

Comment: Don't use `CustomDocumentProperties`. If you want to get the creation date of an Excel file, use `BuiltinDocumentProperties`...

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I am a total beginner in c#. But how can I extract the creation date from the properties?

Comment: Couldn't you just skip Interop and use `File.GetCreationTime`?

Comment: If you are a beginner, i suggest to spend some time with some tutorials/guides about "Office Interop Objects" / Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (as well as the documentation for the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel API). StackOverflow as a question&answer site is a poor place looking for tutoring/mentoring.

Comment: @Parrish Husband Perfect. I did not know this command. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Creation Date` can be found in the [BuiltinDocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties?view=vsto-2017) property which returns a `Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties` collection that represents all the built-in document properties for the workbook.

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties;

properties = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)Globals.ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties; 

Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperty prop;
prop = properties["Creation Date"];
```

See [How to: Read from and write to document properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-read-from-and-write-to-document-properties?view=vs-2019) for more information.